# HTML forms, JSON and PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a HTML form which is parsed into JSON using stringify and then communicated to a mysqli database.

The problem I have is that the form contains quite a few checkboxes which will be checked when relevant and only checked checkboxes get output on the form submit action. This means that when I am reading the JSON back in later I am never sure of the structure of it, making accessing particular elements of the decoded json array impossible.

The form checkbox section looks like this:

```
​                    <!-- Couriers section --> 
                <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="ppd" class="col-sm-5 col-form-label">Courier Select</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-6">
                         <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="courierCheck" id="courierAmazon" value="amazon">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="courierAmazon">Amazon Logistics</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="courierCheck" id="courierDHL" value="dhl">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="courierCheck">DHL</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="courierCheck" id="courierDPD" value="dpd">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="courierDPD">DPD</label>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="courierCheck" id="courierFedex" value="fedex">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="courierFedex">FedEx</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="courierCheck" id="courierGFS" value="gfs">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="courierGFS">GFS</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="courierCheck" id="courierHermes" value="hermes">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="courierHermes">Hermes</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="courierCheck" id="courierInterlink" value="interlink">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="courierInterlink">Interlink</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="courierCheck" id="courierIntersoft" value="intersoft">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="courierIntersoft">Intersoft</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="courierCheck" id="courierMetapack" value="metapack">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="courierMetapack">MetaPack</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="courierCheck" id="courierNetdespatch" value="netdespatch">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="courierNetdespatch">NetDespatch</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="courierCheck" id="courierNightfreight" value="nightfreight">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="courierNightfreight">NightFreight</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="courierCheck" id="courierParcelforce" value="parcelforce">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="courierParcelforce">ParcelForce</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="courierCheck" id="courierRoyalmail" value="royalmail">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="courierRoyalmail">RoyalMail</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="courierCheck" id="courierTNT" value="tnt">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="courierTNT">TNT</label>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="courierCheck" id="courierTuffnells" value="tuffnells">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="courierTuffnells">Tuffnells</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="courierCheck" id="courierUPS" value="ups">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="courierUPS">UPS</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="courierCheck" id="courierXDP" value="xdp">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="courierXDP">XDP</label>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="courierCheck" id="courierYodel" value="yodel">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="courierYodel">Yodel</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And the JSON string looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "contactNameInput",
    "value": "Name"
  },
  {
    "name": "companyNameInput",
    "value": "Company"
  },
  {
    "name": "companyRegNumberInput",
    "value": "23456"
  },
  {
    "name": "quoteNumberInput",
    "value": "Q4356"
  },
  {
    "name": "version",
    "value": "Professional Edition"
  },
  {
    "name": "userInput",
    "value": "12"
  },
  {
    "name": "kpafUserInput",
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "hhtUserInput",
    "value": "n/a"
  },
  {
    "name": "ppdUserInput",
    "value": "n/a"
  },
  {
    "name": "eposUserInput",
    "value": "n/a"
  },
  {
    "name": "courierCheck",
    "value": "interlink"
  },
  {
    "name": "courierCheck",
    "value": "intersoft"
  },
  {
    "name": "courierCheck",
    "value": "nightfreight"
  },
  {
    "name": "trainingCheck",
    "value": "accounts"
  },
  {
    "name": "trainingCheck",
    "value": "channels"
  },
  {
    "name": "dataDays",
    "value": "2"
  },
  {
    "name": "dataCheck",
    "value": "stock"
  },
  {
    "name": "dataCheck",
    "value": "customer"
  }
]
```

My requirement is to read this JSON string in and decode it into an array and use the elements to populate an HTML based document. The way I am accessing the elements currently is like this:

```
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $quotationData = json_decode($row["json"], true);

        $qname = $quotationData[0]['value'];
        $qnumber = $quotationData[3]['value'];
```

But as the user selects courier integration checkbox options, the value in the array obviously increased therefore making it impossible to target the information I need.

Can someone please review and let me know the correct way to approach this to obtain the result and usability I am struggling for?

Comment: If I understood your problem correctly, you can just use resultype "MYSQLI_ASSOC":
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

"Returns an associative array of strings representing the fetched row in the result set, where each key in the array represents the name of one of the result set's columns or NULL if there are no more rows in resultset."

Or use mysqli_fetch_assoc():
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

This will make your keys your columns names and you can access their values directly and not have to worry about indices shifting.

Comment: Thanks @Rami I think I might have to control this better from the db. Currently the database only has 3 columns - ID, quoteNumber, JSON - whereby the encoded JSON string is dumped into the last column and then retrieved later.

Comment: That is interesting, using a relational db I have never stored raw JSON into a column to later extract and parse the data from said column. I believe you would be better served having specific columns and storing their respective values. This I believe would simplify things for you. Alternatively I would imagine a document store such as mongo would lend itself better for the storing/processing of JSON.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's rather lazy of me. I was going for efficiency but just caused myself restrictions. Thank you for your advise

Answer (score 0):

try adding brackets to name, which makes your checkboxes into an array of values

```
name="courierCheck[]"
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that and the JSON came back as {
    "name": "courierCheck[]",
    "value": "interlink"
  },
  {
    "name": "courierCheck[]",
    "value": "intersoft"
  },
  {
    "name": "courierCheck[]",
    "value": "nightfreight"